# A question on Determinantal Point Process on calculating probabilities

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, determinant

I'm reading some references on Determinantal Point Process, and found the following proposition:

Let $\mathcal {T}$ be a determinantal point process with correlation kernel
$K$. Let $E_1$, $E_2 \subset X$, then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(E_{1}\subset \mathcal {T},E_{2}\cap \mathcal {T}=\emptyset\right)=\sum_{A\subset E_{2}}(-1)^{\vert A\vert}\text{det}\left(K_{E_{1}\cup A}\right).
\end{align*}

I wonder if there's any proof of this proposition or an explanation on why this is true. Anway, if this proposition is true, two special cases are formed by either taking $E_{1}=\emptyset$ or $E_{2}=E^{\complement}_{1}$. In the first case, I have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb {P}\left(E\subset \mathcal {T}^{\complement}\right)=\sum_{A\subset E}(-1)^{\vert A\vert}\text{det}\left(K_{A}\right)=\text{det}\left(I-K_{E}\right),
\end{align*}

which in fact says that $\mathcal {T}^\complement$ is also a deteminantal point process given that $\mathcal {T}$ is. In the second case, I have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb {P}\left(E=\mathcal {T}\right)=(-1)^{\vert E\vert}\sum_{A\subset E}(-1)^{\vert A\vert}\text{det}\left(K_{A}\right),
\end{align*}
which I'm not quite sure about why this is true. Any hints or available references are appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula actually has very little to do with determinantal measures, and is just inclusion-exclusion.  An easy example is the following:  For any random set $T$ and fixed set $E \subset X$, inclusion-exclusion says $$\mathbb{P}(E \cap T = \emptyset) = \sum_{S \subset E} (-1)^{|S|} \mathbb{P}(S \subset T)\,.$$

Similarly, for any $E_1, E_2$, we have $$\mathbb{P}(E_1 \subset T, E_2 \cap T = \emptyset) = \sum_{S \subset E_2} (-1)^{|S|} \mathbb{P}(E_1 \subset T, S \subset T)\,.$$

For your question, we have $\mathbb{P}(E_1 \subset T, S \subset T) = \det(K_{E_1 \cup S})$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Hello, sir. Thank you for your answer. I wonder in the case of $E_{2}=E^{\complement}_{1}$, is there a matrix, say, $M^{E}$ such that the right hand side of $\mathbb {P}(E=\mathcal {T})$ can be written as det($M^{E}$)? Thanks.